# Selenium Service ignoring executable_path?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, service, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm on Selenium 4.1.5, and when I try to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=f'./chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

I get

> Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
> Current browser version is 102.0.5005.63 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Thing is, I haven't changed anything in the directory and it's been running peachy-keen up until today randomly. I can manually open chromedriver and see it's v100, so my guess is executable_path is being ignored? I've also tried the deprecated non-service inline path setting to no avail. Hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try updating your Chrome from 100 to 102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [chromedriver-autoinstaller](https://github.com/yeongbin-jo/python-chromedriver-autoinstaller) to do it all at once:

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller as chromedriver
chromedriver.install()
```

Alternatively use [chromedriver-binary-auto](https://github.com/danielkaiser/python-chromedriver-binary) to find the required version and install the driver:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall chromedriver-binary-auto
import chromedriver_binary
```

**OR**

Update the chrome version using the [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and reboot

Comment: Man, that's so odd. I do want to say that the first solution _did_ work, so thank you!

I also want to mention that the last bit is the one I expected to work but it didn't. What's even more peculiar is I copied the directory to a different machine and it ran fine. Then I updated my personal Chrome (not ChromeDriver, and Chrome was already an incompatible version ahead of Selenium beforehand) and it borked it in the same way, but I'm unsure of why it'd behave that way if ChromeDriver is a separate entity. 

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: if your issue is resolved, so can you please accept the answer.